# How to use slice from mutable Vec as key in the HashMap

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a simple program that stores a short sequence (`let sample: Vec<u32>`) in the main vector (`let mut samplesTable: Vec<Vec<u32>>`)
and has search index that maps that sequences to their corresponding index in the main vector.

A sequences represent statistic samples for some experiment. I need to be able to find the ID (the index in the `samplesTable`) of a sample by its content.

Memory requirements will be high so the architecture of program better avoid redundancy.
So the search index is just a `HashMap<&[u32], u32>`, where the first parameter is the full slice of sample from `samplesTable`, and the second is the corresponding index of that sample.

The multithreaded version will be the next step.

This pattern is very important to me so I must to find a way to implement it in Rust.

---

What I've tried so far:

1. Wrap all call sites of `addSample` in "{}" to create another scope.
2. Switched to nightly and forced `#![feature(nll)]`

I'm using Windows 7 with Rust versions 1.35 and 1.36.

I'm using no external crates, it's a plain "cargo new --bin".

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Adds new sample to the table with the given index and updates index map.
// If there is an old sample, we insert the new sample with the 'id' from the old one.
// In this case 'id; parameter is should be zero and ignored in the function.
fn addSample<'a, 'b: 'a>(
    oldSample: Option<Vec<u32>>,
    newSample: Vec<u32>,
    id: u32,
    samplesTable: &'b mut Vec<Vec<u32>>,
    indexMap: &'a mut HashMap<&'a [u32], u32>,
) {
    // We have the oldSample, then replace it with the new one
    if let Some(oldSampleTmp) = oldSample {
        let oldID = indexMap.remove(oldSampleTmp.as_slice());

        if let Some(oldId) = oldID {
            samplesTable[oldId as usize] = newSample;

            let slice: &[u32] = samplesTable[oldId as usize].as_slice();
            indexMap.insert(slice, oldId);
        } else {
            panic!(
                "addSample: oldSampleTmp was not found!\n  oldSampleTmp={:?}",
                oldSampleTmp
            )
        };
    }
    // We don't have the oldSample, so just insert newSample with provided 'id'
    else {
        samplesTable[id as usize] = newSample;

        let slice: &[u32] = samplesTable[id as usize].as_slice();
        indexMap.insert(slice, id);
    }
} // end of the "addSample" function

fn main() {
    // init our tables
    let mut indexMap: HashMap<&[u32], u32> = HashMap::new();

    let mut samplesTable: Vec<Vec<u32>> = Vec::with_capacity(3);

    // prepare the sample data
    let sampleA: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let sampleB: Vec<u32> = vec![4, 5, 6];
    let sampleC: Vec<u32> = vec![7, 8, 9];

    // trying to fill the tables
    addSample(None, sampleA, 1, &mut samplesTable, &mut indexMap);
    addSample(None, sampleB, 2, &mut samplesTable, &mut indexMap);
    addSample(None, sampleC, 3, &mut samplesTable, &mut indexMap);

    // debug print
    println!("indexMap is {:?}", &indexMap);
    println!("index is {:?}", indexMap.get(vec![1, 2, 3].as_slice()));
}
```

The problem is that Rust generates this error:

> error[E0499]: cannot borrow `samplesTable` as mutable more than once at a time

As far as I understand all modifications are contained in the body of "addSample".
So after first call there should be no problem with the others in the same scope.